# Kill a Python process if it doesn't finish in a certain time?

Tags: python, multithreading, process

Here's the scenario:
I have a Python script that is called from a browser with AJAX.  I want the Python script to run and return its output, however if it fails to successfully run in 10 seconds, I want the script to abort and return some other process.  Also, at the very beginning, I want to log what the request was.

Here's how I'm thinking of architecting it:
Commander script
  Calls three scripts, spawned as subprocesses?
    1. the main code to execute and return its result
    2. a second script, that waits 10 seconds, then returns False
    3. a third script, to log the request in a database
The commander script will return either the result from (1) or an error if it hears back from (2).

How would you actually implement this?  I can't figure out if I should use the threading library or the os library with subprocesses.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly sugges using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) library of Python. It has `process.terminate()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

If this script is run under Unix-like system, you may use SIGALRM to do it.
There's an example in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#example).

Answer (score 0):

check out: 
[subprocess.Popen.poll](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)
and
[subprocess.Popen.terminate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate)

Comment: if you're using Python 2, check out [`subprocess32`](https://github.com/google/python-subprocess32) for access to versions of the linked methods with the `timeout` parameter -- it was added in Python 3.3, IIRC.